# JavaScript Nested While Loop, Loops infinitely

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, nested

So I'm trying to create a loop that will reduce any number put into it to a single digit. The way I'm doing my math is adding each number up one by one. In this case 9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9=108. I want it to run through and check that 108 is still greater than 9 and do it till the result is less than 9.  It just gets stuck in a loop. I've also tried some variants that will return NaN.

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Reduce Loop</h1>

<p id="Result"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
//Defined var start
var Result = 0;
var TempReduce1 = 0;
var LoopTempLength = 0;
var LoopTempString;
var i = 0;
//Defined var end
//The LongNumber variable represents user input
var LongNumber = 999999999999;
//Converts LongNumber to a integer
var LoopTemp = parseInt(LongNumber);
//Check if LoopTemp is greater than 9; it is
while (LoopTemp > 9) {
    //Gets the Length of LoopTemp by converting it to a string and grabbing the length to then convert back to a integer
    LoopTempLength = parseInt(LoopTemp.toString().length);
    //Converts LoopTemp to a string for manipulation
    LoopTempString = LoopTemp.toString();
    i = 0;
    //Check to see if i is less than the length of LoopTempLength
    while (i < LoopTempLength) {
        //Grabs the number in relationship to i, converts it to a integer and added it to TempReduce1
        TempReduce1 += parseInt(LoopTempString.charAt(i));
        i++;
    }
    LoopTemp = TempReduce1;
}   
Result = LoopTemp;

        document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = Result;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the state change at each step? How does this differ from what should happen?

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not sure. This is the first time I've tried to use JavaScript. I'm not entirely sure how to debug it properly. All I can tell you is when I try to run the code it locks up and crashes. Indicating to me that it got stuck in a loop. Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: You never reset `TempReduce1`, so you are always adding to the last amount, You then assign it back to `LoopTemp` so it is never going to be less than 9, unless the initial loop doesn't add up to 9

Comment: Change the script and put the word `debugger` at the top of it. Open in Chrome. Ctrl+Shift+i to open dev tools. Refresh the page and step through it.

Comment: @BenAston So change `<script type="text/javascript">` to `<script type="debugger">`

Comment: No. Put the word `debugger` on the line before `var Result = 0;`. In the code.

Comment: I know your goal is to learn the loops and figure out the debugging. But believe it or not, taking the LongNumber mod 9 would suffice to get the result (and if the result is 0, say 9, not 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Patrick Evans has it right. I inserted

```
TempReduce1=0;
```

in your code after the line

```
i=0
```

and the routine kicked out 9 as one would expect.

Comment: Thank You! That seems to have fixed my issue!